# Kendall's plot, copula dependence measure, Matlab, R

Tags: r, statistics

I want to write a code to plot Kendall's plot.
This piece is written in **R**

```
    n=nrow(X)
i=rep(1:n,each=n)
j=rep(1:n,n)
S=((X[i,1]>X[j,1])&(X[i,2]>X[j,2]))
Z=tapply(S,i,sum)/(n-1)
```

I worte this one in **Matlab** :

```
 y=[y1,y2]
k=1;
for i=1:10;
    for j=1:10;
        idx_2=find(y1<0.1*(i) & y2<0.1*(j) & i~=j);
        C(k)=length(idx_2);
        k=k+1;
    end
end
```

However I think there is something wrong with the way that I did it.
so my question is :
1-Can you help me write the R code in Matlab?
2- Is there something wrong with the way that I am doing it?
3- Do you have any other suggestion on how to cacluate Kendall distribution in Matlab